# LDTP configuration(Linux Desktop testing project) configuration on pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I have installed PyCharm and I want to install the LDTP package into it. However, when I am installing through UI and command prompt, I am getting an issue. Attached is the screenshot. Please help me in fixing this issue.

[image]

Comment: Try updating pip first by running the command `python -m pip install -U pip` on a terminal.

Comment: After that what i supposed to do..

Comment: After that try running the command `pip install ldtp` in a terminal.

Comment: Again the same error is observed..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to do then. I was just going off of the suggestions in the screenshot.